# Phaser: this.game is undefined in the Update function

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

Good evening,
sorry for asking again, but I need to be done with this by tomorrow for school. Basically, when I try to access the this.game variable in the update function, it says that it is undefined, to be specific, I get this; "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined".
In my update function I have this:

```
create: function() {
    [...]
    map.setCollisionByExclusion([], true, doorLayer);
    [...]
}
```

When I try to access this.game in the update function on the collision action, I get the error mentioned above.
Here's the code;

```
update: function() {
    [...]
    this.game.physics.arcade.collide(player, doorLayer, function() {
        if (hasItem) {
            this.game.state.start('Hallway'); //This is where I get the error
        }
    });
    [...]
}
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.game.physics.arcade.collide(player, doorLayer, function() {
        if (hasItem) {
            this.game.state.start('Hallway'); //This is where I get the error
        }
    });`

Notice the inner `this` refers to the anonymous function you are passing which clearly does not have a member named `game`.

Ideally, rename `this` to something else and then use it.
Now you can use `myself` variable inside the anonymous function passed and access `myself`'s properties.

i.e.

`var myself = this;`